# Why aren't bpy.props defined on the WindowManager saved on permanently?

Tags: python

I can create a checkbox with `bpy.props.BoolProperty`. I can set a default for it. `True` or `False`. Let's say we start with `False`. And my user wants the value to be `True`. Permanently. The problem is, when i restart Blender, then the bool is reset to the default value. And this also when i save the user preferences or the startup.blend

Is there a way to save the current state of the `BoolProperty` so that the user doesn't have to adjust it all the time?

Examplecode:

```
import bpy

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Checkbox"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        wm = context.window_manager # Our bool is in the windows_manager
        layout.prop(wm, "checkbox_bool") # Our checkbox

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    #Our bool
    bpy.types.WindowManager.checkbox_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="A checkbox", description="Do this or that", default = False)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.checkbox_bool # Unregister our flag when unregister.
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The window-manager is an exception when it comes to data-blocks, having some characteristics that make it work differently then meshes, scenes... etc.

- Can't be added or removed.
- Its a *singleton* (there is only ever one).
- Its not saved in the blend file (this is why properties aren't set on reload).

This can be handy, for example - this is used for the add-on and key-map search text fields.

For persistent data, its normally best to use...

- the current scene (`context.scene`).
- [add-on-preferences](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html)
- in a sub-directory of [user resources](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.user_resource) (as json/xml/pickled data... etc).